# is it correct to use synchronous code in a nodejs worker process?

Tags: node.js, web-worker

I have a redis queue of long and boring stuff to do, that gets filled by my main http server. This queue is then slowly processed by another server that I use as a worker (heroku worker). When this process has finished an item, it saves the result to the database.

Is it ok to code my nodejs worker process in a synchronous way? It does make sense to me since it does one thing at a time anyway and does not have to answer to any request.

Comment: Is there any possibility that worker server will get second item while still proceeding on the previous one?

Comment: I think that I may actually happen only in a asynchronous scenario, otherwise it will be pretty straightforward: get item at index 0, process it, save it elsewhere, delete item at index 0. and so on till the end of the queue.

Comment: So of course it makes sense. Javascript never runs parallely so there is no need for asynchronous design. It's just for otherwise blocking operations

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use synchronous code to develop a worker process for Redis. So you want to make your keys file for your Redis host and port:

```
module.exports = {
  redisHost: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  redisPort: process.env.REDIS_PORT
};
```

So when you want to connect to `redis` you look for the hostname or url for `redis` and the port you are supposed to connect from your environment variable.

Then require that in along with `redis`:

```
const keys = require("./keys");
const redis = require("redis");
```

Then create your `redisClient` like so:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: keys.redisHost,
  port: keyof.redisPort,
  retry_strategy: () => 1000
});
```

The `retry_strategy:` tells the worker that if we lose connection, retry connecting once every second.